# load javascript library meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Meteor project with subpage using javascript library (d3.js) - quite large so I don't want Meteor to load d3 before actually needing it (many users will not be needing it)

How do include the js-file? (I don't want to use CDN)

Using Iron-router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place it in the public folder and then whenever you need it, you can load it using [jQuery's getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) as in:

```
jQuery.getScript( /d3.v3.min.js)
```

You don't need iron-router specific syntax here. Just use this snippet within your template's rendered callback and that's it.

Or if you really want to declare this in your route, you can do so:

```
after: function () {
  jQuery.getScript( /d3.v3.min.js);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - didn't realize that folder also was meant for this.

Comment: Your welcome. There is also talks about lazy loading to be officially built in to meteor core, so you might want to keep an eye out on post v1.0 updates.